# Center icons that has been floated

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to center a number of icons that has been floated to the left ?

```
.facebook{
  background-image: url('icons/facebook.png');
}

.social-icons{
  height: 48px;
  width: 48px;
  margin: 10px;
  float: left;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="facebook social-icons"></div>
```

I tried making a new DIV and setting the margin to `0 auto` but it didnt seem to change the position as it's been overwritten by the float. Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: I didn't include it as it didn't work. However, there's a margin set for the social icons class.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution for it.

I had to use an `inline-block` element to make it act like a block element. Safe to say this effectively replaces floats in HTML5.